# django orm get foreign key values

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two tables,

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="a")
```

I need the result set as follows,

```
[{ "name":"a",
   "a":[
        {"name":"a1"}, {"name":"b1"}, {"name":"c1"}]
}, { "name":"b",
   "b":[
        {"name":"a2"}]
}]
```

Sample table data

```
A

id    name
------------
1    a
2    b



B

id    name   a
---------------
1    a1     1
2    b1     1
3    c1     1
4    a2     2
```

How would I achieve my desired result in django orm? I tried

```
  a_ob  = A.objects.get(id=1)
  b_ob = a_ob.a.all()
```

which would give me two results and i would combine both. When I want to get all records in table A without filtering by id, what would I use. (without for loop in orm)

Comment: **"When I want to get all records in table A, what would I use"** what do you mean? from which instance do you want to get these records? from b instance, you can only have on instance from a, because of the FOreign Key

Comment: _When I want to get all records in table A, what would I use_ - `A.objects.all()`?

Comment: @hoefling I need along with related records in B table

Comment: You can't have more than one record in table A from B instance, B has a `ForeignKey` to A.. but with a `ManyTOManyField`, you can